# Email, Yahoo messenger, Skype in one app?

Tags: windows, email, chat, skype

I am looking for a Windows application supports the following features : 
1. Multiprotocol IM : Yahoo messenger, Skype, ...
2. Email client (POP3 or IMAP, SMTP).
Is there any app like this already existed ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/?utm_campaign=vid&utm_source=vid&utm_medium=vid&utm_content=vid). It supports Yahoo, Email and multi protocols.

Answer (score 3):

[Pidgin](https://www.pidgin.im/) can do most IM networks such as Yahoo, and Skype text chat with a [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/skype4pidgin/) (but you need Skype installed also :( ). It doesn't do email, but it can [notify you when new mail arrives](http://www.howtogeek.com/102919/5-tips-and-tricks-for-pidgin-users/) for certain protocols.

Comment: Pidgin does skype-web with a plug-in without needing to have skype installed